# Why do almost all of the ERC20 tokens have even number of decimals?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, decimals

I'm thinking of creating a token with a decimal point of odd number.
However I'm kind of worried if there is any issue that can be caused by using an odd number for the decimal point.

Is there any reason that why do almost all of the ERC20 tokens have even number of decimals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific reason for this.

Most tokens use 18 decimals in order to achieve a high level of precision and to mimic the precision of ETH. Some use 2 decimals to mimic a fiat currency. Some use 8 decimals to mimic Bitcoin.

An odd number of decimals would work fine in all protocols that I know of today.

Comment: so 3,5,7,9 is fine?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.